# Sonarqube integration with existing Oracle 12c

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

I am trying to integrate SonarQube 5 latest with Oracle 12c. My Oracle DB is existing and I use one of users with enough CRUD privileges to allow SonarQube to connect and create the necessary structures.

However, on starting the SonarQube server, I get exception complaining that DB is using character encoding other than UTF-8. I can not change DB encoding. Is there a setting in properties which can avoid this or set coding scheme in SonarQube as what is there in DB so that it does not complain on mismatch?

I am not sure why SonarQube would need certain DB configuration. It should seamlessly work with existing DBs without complaining on NLS or char encoding as those are larger decisions made for a firm once and new tools should be able to support that.

This is what it is related to: [SONAR-6171](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6171)

Is there a way to disable this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a requirement for quite some time. See also [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) requirements page. After implementing SONAR-6171 this is checked explicitly.